# Injection proof $f(m/n)$

Tags: analysis, functions

Prove $f(m/n)=2^m3^n$, $m/n$ is in lowest term, is an injection.
I have learnt injection for $x_1=x_2, f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. I would like to ask how to deal with $m/n$. Thanks.

Comment: What is $f(2./2)$?  What is $f(1/1)$?

Comment: sorry $m/n$ is in lowest term, I forget to add the condition. I'll edit it

Comment: Apply uniquensess part of prime factorization theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets prove that your function is one to one function.
That is:
$f(a/b) = f(c/d) \implies a/b = c/d$
$$f(a/b) = 2^a\cdot 3^b = 2^c\cdot 3^d = f(c/d)$$
Then $2^{a-c} = 3^{d-b}$
Since the left and the right side have no common divisor, the only solution is that both must be 1.
$a-c = 0$ and $d-b=0$ or $a=c$ and $b=d$ 
Which means $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$